# Potential problems from passing macro arguments to \verb

Tags: macros, verbatim, catcodes

I've been working on a command that will typeset snippets of code within a paragraph.  I'm aware of `listings` and company, but I want something that will just typeset the code verbatim and also allow me to do other things with it (like save to an external file and then execute).

I've created a macro that typesets its argument using `\verb` and also could make its argument available for other purposes.  But in the process of creating it, I keep reading about how verb isn't meant to take arguments (even though I seem to have gotten it to do so).  So two questions:

- Is there anything that can go terribly wrong with this code?  Is there some deep reason that `\verb` is not to be tampered with?
- What is going on with the catcodes?  It seems that `\verb`'s delimiting character must be active.  This leads to some really strange behavior.  For example, I can use "=" as my delimiter, and typeset code that contains "=", so long as the delimiter isn't the last character in my `\createverb` macro.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\catcode`\==\active
\gdef\delimchar{=}
\gdef\delimchardetok{\detokenize{=}}
\endgroup
\verbtocs{\cmd}|\verb|
\def\createverb{%
    \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    %Reset the \, {, and } so they're special
    \catcode`\\=0
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    %Obey spaces
    \frenchspacing\@vobeyspaces
    \createverb@finish}
\def\createverb@finish#1{%
    %Deactiveate { and } 
    \catcode`\{=12
    \catcode`\}=12
    \tokenize{\verbtext}{\cmd\delimchardetok\detokenize{#1}}%
    \endgroup
    \verbtext\delimchar%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Pseudo-Perl:

\createverb{$f=$_[0]+$a{$b[2]}+$c*$d  #Comment here}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may be interested in the `xparse` package and its verbatim argument type. E.g., try `\DeclareDocumentCommand{\foo}{v}{\typeout{#1}}`.

Comment: Also read: [Why doesn’t verbatim work within...?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbwithin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Bruno's suggestion, here is an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\createverb}{ov}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {{\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily#2}}
    {\def#1{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\createverb{$f=$_[0]+$a{$b[2]}+$c*$d  #Comment here}

\createverb[\xyz]{$f=$_[0]+$a{$b[2]}+$c*$d  #Comment here}

\xyz

\end{document}
```

I don't see anything "dangerous" in your code; but it's quite awkward.